# rEFInd possiblities, on MacBook Pro?

Tags: 14.04, macbook

I've installed Ubuntu on my MacBook and it is running fine, but when I boot into `rEFInd`, I got a possiblity called

```
boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-28-generic.efi.signed from Apple_HFS_Untitled_2
```

Is this needed? If not how can I delete it? I'm running Ubuntu as the only OS on my Mac? Can I make it boot that by default?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove it as seen [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/188190/191609).

There are other boot manager alternatives and you could simply use the pre-installed boot menu via power on holding the alt/option. Although the efi boot menu may not detect Ubuntu at all, so it is more reliable to use a boot manager.